# Fixed navbar disappears and then reappears

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a navbar which becomes fixed when it reaches the top of the screen by adding a class via jquery . The problem is that when it reaches the top of the screen it disappears and then reappears when I scroll some more so I need to prevent it disappearing

```js
(function ($) {
    "use strict";

    var menuPosition = function () {
        var nav = $(".menu"),
            height = nav.height(),
            windowHeight = $(window).height();

        if ($(window).scrollTop() > (windowHeight - height))
            nav.addClass('fixed');
        else 
            nav.removeClass('fixed');        
    };

    menuPosition();
    $(document).scroll(menuPosition);
}(jQuery));
```

```css
.menu {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 25px 0px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
    color: white;
}

.fixed {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
}

<div style="height: 80vh; width: 100%; background: #262626"></div>
<ul class="menu">
    <li>about</li>
    <li>projects</li>
    <li>contact</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you provide html code?

Comment: my bad . have edited to include html

Answer (score 0):

Use `outerHeight()` instead of `height()` for this line:

```
height = nav.height()
```

Comment: still the same result . it only disappears for about 10 pixels and then appears again . strange . what looks to be happening is that the effect doesn't come into play until the bottom of the .menu passes the top of the screen as opposed to the top of the .menu which would be the desired effect . i wonder would some use of offset be the thing to do?

Comment: What do you mean by 'disappears', is it overflow or literally hidden? I don't see the menu container be hidden from your code, check this out: http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=21234217142829294623&t=2123421714282929462321038

Comment: saying it disappears was probably the wrong way to describe the problem . what's happening is it scrolls off screen the way an element without fixed positioning would and then after i scroll about 100 pixels more it sort of abruptly appears at the top of the screen . it's as if the fixed class is being added only after the navbar has scrolled 100 pixels off screen as opposed to when it reaches the top of the screen

Comment: Have you tried my upload on the comment above? Does the bug occur in there?

Comment: yeah the same issue is occurring with it . scrolls off screen and then pops up after continued scrolling . i tried giving the .menu a defined height but that made no difference